# How do I open a private static website using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

I'm building a website where people log in to view personal reports. Each report consists of multiple HTML, CSS, and media files. Reports should open in the browser.

I'm currently using boto3 to generate a presigned URLs for individual HTML files in a private S3 bucket. How do I access reports consisting of multiple files?

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
url = s3client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'my-bucket',
        'Key': 'my-website/index.html',
    }
) # url shows html content but no CSS styling or media files
```

Comment: The best you could do with S3 to host a static site while keeping it private would be to configure the bucket for public static site hosting, but then add an S3 bucket policy that only allows certain IP addresses, or only a VPC endpoint or something (depending on how you want to connect to the site).

Comment: You say it is a "private" website, but how do you define "private"? Who should be allowed to access it, and how would you identify such people? For example, are they all in one location (eg a corporate network)? Or would you expect them to 'login' to the website to authenticate? An Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL only provides access to a **single object for a limited time period**. Were you wanting something similar for a whole website, where anyone with a 'magical' URL can obtain access?

Comment: I'm building a website where people log in to view their personal HTML reports. Each report consists of multiple HTML, CSS, and media files.

Answer (score 0):

To secure your website while connecting from web browser, you will need an `SSL certificate`. SSL certificates can not be attached directly to S3 static website, to accomplish this, you can create a `CloudFront` distribution which is using s3 bucket as an origin and attach SSL certificate to CloudFront. Create a custom domain Route53 record that is pointing your Cloudfront distribution. You can access your application via browser securely after these steps.
To restrict incoming traffic with certain rule sets, you can attach `WAF` **(Web Application Firewall)** to your CloudFront distribution and deny all IPs/Networks other than yours.

Reference :

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-awswaf.html

Comment: That encrypts the traffic, but still makes the entire website public. It doesn't really protect anything here.

Comment: @MarkB Sorry, when I read "securing the website" I immediately thought SSL implementation, my bad. Also you can still do this by attaching one more component to the stack above, which is WAF. By attaching WAF to CloudFront, incoming traffic can be restricted by certain rules. I edited my answer.